# nodejs - how to ensure my application is reliable all the time

Tags: node.js, nginx, npm, pm2, forever

I have been using forverjs for my server but for some reason the server stopped and the server didn't restart again. Is foreverjs reliable?

Should i use any other libs?

Found there are many libs like pm2, nodemon, upstart, systemd, nginx. Which one should ensure my application running all the time. also can these tools handle large loads of requests?

Comment: I like pm2, but I also suggest [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) for monitoring (email on stopped services, but I leave node process restarts to pm2, monit is also great for everything "not-node"). Other than that I've found it's all about getting your code to log proper errors so you can prevent the same thing from repeating. Without knowing the errors you can just sit there and scratch your head. "I sure hope this won't happen again!".

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple questions within your question to analyze.

> Is foreverjs reliable?

`forever` is a very popular package.  [As seen on GitHub](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), it has 75 contributors and 636 commits.  This question is mainly opinion-based, but 9/10 (maybe 10/10) experienced developers would say it's reliable **for it's purpose** (I expand below).

> Should i use any other libs?

Reliability is achieved through sturdy software design and not just packages you choose.  I have used `forever` and `pm2` production processes for years without any problems on their end.  They include great features for reliability, such as attempting to restart your application if it crashes.  Packages are not supposed to fix terminal bugs in your code.

> Found there are many libs like pm2, nodemon, upstart, systemd, nginx.
>   Which one should ensure my application running all the time.

This can be found through reading their GitHub descriptions.  I use `nodemon` for quickly testing code as it's written.  For example, I start the `nodemon` process and it begins my `Node.js` process.  When I edit my code and press save, the `Node.js` process is automatically stopped and restarted with the new code.  `nodemon` should not be used alone for a long-running production server, since it will stop when you exit your shell.  `pm2` and `forever` are effective libraries and you can investigate `upstart`, `systemd`, and `nginx` if necessary.

Regarding @Kalana Demel's answer, I consider using `forever` to run `nodemon` as using `forever` in my explanation above.

> how to ensure my application is reliable all the time

For an overall answer to your question, you should be writing tests to ensure your code is reliable.  If you've written effective unit and integration tests, choosing a package to run the process will be trivial (and not related to reliability), since you should not expect it to crash.

Answer (score 0):

nodemon is a good option, you can use a combination of forever and nodemon using,

```
forever start -c nodemon app.js
```

Also in my experience forever is very reliable, try

```
forever logs app.js
```

to see what exactly caused the error

Answer (score 0):

**pm2** is good option in these cases, I personally use pm2 in all my node.js servers, it provides alot of more important functionalities in comparison to others. 
One of the best thing about it can be easily integrated with keymetrics/newrelic for analytics of the server.
Also pm2 will give you cpu/memory usage, you can even configure the restart limit and interval.